# An error in apache derby when I try to display data from BLOB field

Tags: java, blob, derby

I am using Netbeans to do some application communicating with a database where I create some columns as `BLOB`. I created a new view which contains those Blob columns, and when I try to display the contained data of the view (by right clicking mouse and click Show data*), I have this error:

> The data in this BLOB or CLOB is no longer available. The BLOB/CLOB's transaction may be committed, or its connection is closed.

I search on the net but there is no clear answer to this problem, any help please?

Comment: Is the transaction committed? Is the connection closed?

Comment: @BryanPendleton "Transaction is not commited" I just do a select and ths connection is not closed

Comment: Remember that JDBC connections are in auto-commit mode by default. Are you SURE your transaction is not committed?

Comment: @BryanPendleton this is just select request . as I said in my question   "when I try to display the contained data of the view", and I can see the blob when I do my select from the table

Comment: Select statements are contained within transactions, and can be committed, too.